# Check a range is not the entire sheet?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have this function which is trying to detect when a particular cell value changes. The problem is, if the user selects the whole spreadsheet and presses delete, I get an overflow in my check that the range is only a single cell:

```
Public Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Overflow can occur here if range = whole spreadsheet
    If Not IsError(Int(Target.Cells.Count)) Then 
        If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If Target.Cells.Row = 4 And Target.Cells.Column = 1 Then
                Sheets("X").Cells(5, 1).Calculate
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a more elegant way that I can get this code to only run, when a single particular cell value is changed? (with no overflows, problems when I clear the whole worksheet etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are on Excel 2007+ since the number of rows and columns increased dramatically in those versions.  You might have better luck checking to make sure both the row and column count = 1, since those maxes will be much lower than the product of the two (ie, the cell count):

```
If Target.Rows.Count = 1 And Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
```

Comment: Is this full proof or replies on the type of rows.count?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is this onyl working (and Cells.Count didnt work) because the latter used an integer, 16 bits, max value of 65,536 and the whole spreadsheet returned a numbr greater?

Comment: I'm assuming that somewhere behind the scenes VBA is trying to coerce the cell count to a small Integer (16-bit) or Long integer (32-bit).  The cell count of an Excel 2007 worksheet would overflow both of those datatypes.  Unfortunately I can't isolate it right now because I don't have a copy of Excel 2007 handy and cannot actually reproduce your error.

Comment: @mwolfe02 I believe it's this line that's trying to do that. ;-) `Int(Target.Cells.Count)`

Comment: @Gaffi:  I suspected that as well, but I don't think it's the `Int` function itself causing the problem.  To wit, Excel 2007 worksheets have 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns for a total of 17,179,869,184 cells.  In the VBA immediate window, this returns an overflow error: `?1048576 * 16384`, but this: `?CDbl(1048576) * CDbl(16384)` and--more to the point--this: `?Int(17179869184)` do not.

Comment: If I had a copy of Excel 2007 handy, I would check to see if `Debug.Print Target.Cells.Count` returns an overflow when Target is the entire worksheet range.  I'm thinking maybe the `.Count` property of the `Range` object has a datatype of Long integer (as opposed to Double or Variant, which would support the larger sheet size).

Comment: @mwolfe02 I have 2003 and 2010, but not 2007. Using the immediate window only (not a whole captured event, etc.) I get this in '03:  `?Cells.Count / 16777216` -- and this in '10: `?Cells.Count / 16777216`. Now, I don't know about you, but I find that very odd. -- Just checked - same with `Debug.Print` on the event.

Comment: @mwolfe02 Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11730025/698590), as I think it best explains what's going on!

Comment: @Gaffi: Thanks for the link.  Nice follow-up!

Comment: If you use this solution as opposed to [Martin Carlsson's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18461913/1435476) remember to put a closing `Endif` at the end of your code

Answer (score 3):

Use CountLarge instead of Count

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal target As Range)
    If target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    'Code...
End Sub
```

See: [MSDN Range.CountLarge Property (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196838.aspx)