# PivotCaches.create with SourceData exceeding 65535 rows

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Can anybody please explain why I cannot use range with more than 65535 row with Source data when using PivotCaches.Create method?

I am using Excel 2013, also using Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 (which corresponds to xl 2010 if I am not mistaken).

I read I can use name range to solve the issue, but just want to know any reference why current code is not working? Same code works if I just set rng with less than 65535 rows.

```
Set ws = Worksheets("mydata")
Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C66000")

'Set rng = ws.Range("A1:C65000")  THIS WORKS

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=DataRange, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=Worksheets("pvot").Range("A1"), TableName:="mypv", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

ERROR: Error 13, Type Mismatch

Answer (score 1):

I can not explain it. I'd suspect that it has something to do with legacy code and the [CountLarge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18461913/2626313) problem. But I can offer a workaround.

Everything seems to work as expected if instead of

```
SourceData:=Rng
```

you would use

```
SourceData:=Rng.Worksheet.Name & "!" & Rng.Address
```

This expression actually evaluates to string

```
"mydata!$A$1:$C$65000"
```

and this is what Excel 2013 macro recorder uses when recording the `INSERT → Pivot Table` command