# Incorrect value when counting cells in different versions of Excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2003, excel-2010

I have seen some SO users run into an issue when trying to use some variation of `Cells.Count`; the VBA code throws an overflow error in some cases.

For reference, see comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698727/698590):

> I think this will work, but I get an "overflow" error and it points me
>   to the code "If Master.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > 0
>   Then" --- it seems like it's not filtering for anything in particular
>   – user1556069

and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11690898/698590):

> Is this onyl working (and Cells.Count didnt work) because the latter
>   used an integer, 16 bits, max value of 65,536 and the whole
>   spreadsheet returned a numbr greater? – fast_code
>
> ---
>
> I'm assuming that somewhere behind the scenes VBA is trying to coerce
>   the cell count to a small Integer (16-bit) or Long integer (32-bit).
>   The cell count of an Excel 2007 worksheet would overflow both of those
>   datatypes. Unfortunately I can't isolate it right now because I don't
>   have a copy of Excel 2007 handy and cannot actually reproduce your
>   error. – mwolfe02

Trying to understand this, I tried to reproduce myself and got an overflow when trying to assign `Cells.Count` as an Integer. This makes sense as the value is too large for the Integer data type.

Using the code below in both Excel 2003 and 2010, I was given a numeric result when trying to assign as a Long or Variant.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testInteger()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = Cells.Count 'Overflow
    Debug.Print i 'Doesn't get this far...
End Sub

Sub testLong()
    Dim l As Long
    l = Cells.Count
    Debug.Print l 'Prints 16777216 in both versions
End Sub

Sub testVariant()
    Dim v As Variant
    v = Cells.Count
    Debug.Print v 'Prints 16777216 in both versions
End Sub
```

As you can see in my comments, the `Cells.Count` value is `16777216` (which is correct for 2003), but it is the same *for both versions*, and that doesn't make sense to me. To quote [mwolfe02](https://stackoverflow.com/users/154439/mwolfe02) from one of the above-linked answers:

> Excel 2007 worksheets have 1,048,576 rows and 16,384 columns for a total of 17,179,869,184 cells.

Which tells me the value printed in 2010 should be at least (I believe it should really be the same) `17,179,869,184`.

**So why does this number not print correctly/why is the 2003 value returned in 2010?**

Comment: 16777216 is `0x1000000` and 17179869184 is `0x400000000` in hexadecimal just FYI.

Comment: Are you running Excel 2010 in Compatability mode, or looking at a file saved in 2003 format?

Comment: @TimWilliams I started by opening a new Excel 2010 session, which defaulted to Book1, in which I pasted the above code. How do I determine if I am in compat. mode?

Comment: `Debug.Print Rows.Count`

Comment: @TimWilliams In other words, I *should* see the right value once that's been corrected?

Comment: I suspect you will just see an "overflow" error, since **17**,179,869,184 is outside the bounds of even Long (**2**,147,483,647).

Comment: ... or not, as Siddharth points out, if you use `.CountLarge` (had no idea that was there...)

Comment: +1 well written and laid out question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When calculating such large numbers use `.Countlarge` property.

For example

```
Sub CellsCount()
    Dim l As Double
    l = ActiveSheet.Cells.CountLarge
    Debug.Print l
End Sub
```

Also never use `Cells.Count` or `Cells.CountLarge` without specifying the worksheet object. This is to ensure that we don't get incorrect count/error in compatibility mode. Similarly never use `Rows.Count`. Always use `ws.Rows.Count`. This is the most common error people make while trying to find the last row in excel. For example

This

```
lRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

and

```
lRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

might not give you the same results always.

I would also recommend further reading of [this](http://excelusergroup.org/forums/p/314/837.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Sid. I appreciate your insight. (Still, why did MSFT have to have both `.Count` *and* `.CountLarge`...?)

Comment: It is like asking why does MS have Excel 2003 and Excel 2007 :P. `.CountLarge` was introduced with Excel 2007 and was not available with previous versions of Excel. The `Count` property uses the Long Data Type so the largest value it can store is 2,147,483,647. `.CountLarge` uses the Double data Type ehich can handle up to 1.79+E^308.

Comment: +1: For backward compatibility you can include a check based on `val(application.version)>=12` and use Cells.Countlarge if true and Cells.Count otherwise. Note that if using doubles to store integers you can also hit a limit due to the 15 digits of precision ~ 2^50 but this well exceeds the grid size 2^20*2^14=2^34.

Comment: @SiddharthRout For the record, I did try this out while in compatibility mode, and even `.CountLarge` returned `16777216`. So while your point was absolutely correct for avoiding the overflow, Tim Williams' note about this difference should also be considered. Cheers!