# Copying rows into one cell VBA

Tags: excel, vba, row

I've a worksheet with various values in only one column like:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
...
```

And I need a write a simple code that will put this all together in **one** cell (for example D2) and that cell I want to have a value:

```
A;B;C;D;E;F;...
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Do you want an Excel based solution or VBA based? Did you search for similar solution in this [site](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11678370/1389394)? Do you see the **related** questions at the right bottom of this page?

Comment: Excel solution is easy and I used it for a long time, but I can't use it now (the list is changing) and need to upgrade my code. I tried to write it via SQL base, but I felt it is absolutely useless. I wrote only interesing like `recordNumber = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple form, the following VBA macro can do the job (assuming you have values in Excel Worksheet's Column A that you want to concatenate and place a result in the Cell D2):

```
Sub ConcatenateCells()
Dim i As Integer
Dim count As Integer
Dim s As String
count = Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To count
    s = s & Cells(i, 1) & ";"
Next
Range("D2") = s
End Sub
```

You can modify it for your purpose. Also, you may exclude the empty cells by adding the condition:

```
If Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then s = s & Cells(i, 1).Value & ";"
```

Hope this may help. Best regards,

Comment: as simply as I thought... thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome! Good luck with your project. Best regards,

Comment: One question, in string `s` I have only `;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;`, shouldn't be something like `Cells(i, 1).Value`?

Comment: It should work both ways (Value is a default property). Make sure that you put your text in a proper column (A). Best regards,

Comment: AlexBell please do check around related questions before posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you had Googled, you might stumble upon [this link](http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/01/13/combine-text-values-quick-tip/), which is quite funky way of doing it using Excel formula..

```
=CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(A1:A6 & ";"))
```

You just need to make sure that `TRANSPOSE` function is executed using `F9` prior.

However you could always use VBA User Defined Function to get it done too.

Comment: A very nice trick!  Worth remembering.